# Work done in a conservative vector field

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If my vector field is:

$F=(1-\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})i-(\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})j$

How would I go about finding the work done between A(3,2) and B(4, -3)?

I have proved that the vector field is conservative:

$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}-\frac{2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=0$

Can Green's theorem be used in this case?

Comment: Greene's theorem can't be used here because your curve is not the boundary of any region, it's just a line. Now that you know the field is conservative, you know that it is the gradient of some potential function $f$. (ie, $\nabla f = F$). You should find this potential function, and then use the theorem that says $\int _C \nabla f \ ds = f\left(\vec{b}\right) - f\left(\vec{a}\right)$, where $C$ is a curve connecting points $\vec{a}$ to $\vec{b}$.

Comment: So it is a simply a case of setting it up like this: $\int_{3, 2}^{4, -3}(1-\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})dx-(\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})dy$

Comment: Showing that $Q_x - P_y = 0$ is not sufficient to establish that ${\bf F} = P{\bf i} + Q{\bf j}$ is conservative. The usual statement also requires that the domain of $\bf F$ be simply connected ("have no holes"), and that is not the case here, as the domain is punctured at the origin.

Comment: It is an occasionally useful fact that any radial vector field, i.e., one of the form ${\bf F}({\bf r}) = f(||{\bf r}||) {\bf r}$ for some $C^1$ function $f : (0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$, is conservative.

Answer (score 3):

I'll elaborate the idea of @RobBland .

Let us find $f$, so that $\nabla f=\mathbf{F}$. We will do that as follows:

$$
f(x,y)=\int P(x,y)dx=\int\left(1-\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right)dx=x-\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2)+c(y).\tag 1
$$
We assume $y$ to be constant while performing integration $(1)$. $f(x,y)$ satisfies $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=P(x,y)$ condition if and only if it has the form $(1)$. Here $c(y)$ is some arbitrary (smooth enough) function; it depends only on $y$.

Now we should find $c(y)$ using $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=Q(x,y)$ condition. We will differentiate $(1)$ by $y$:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2)+c(y)\right)=-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}+c^\prime(y).\tag2
$$

But $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ should equal $Q(x,y)=-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$:
$$
-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}+c^\prime(y)=-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}.
$$
Thus we obtain $c^\prime=0$, so $c=\mathrm{const}$. Now we got the potential:
$$
f(x,y)=x-\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2)+c,
$$
here $c$ is an arbitrary constant, that may be omitted.

Now we obtain readily:
$$
\mathrm{Work}_{A\to B}=f(B)-f(A)=f(4,-3)-f(3,2)=\left[x-\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2)\right]\Bigg|^{(4,-3)}_{(3,2)}=\\
=1-\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{25}{13}
$$

**REMARK**

$f(x,y)$ may be found easier, if we recall, that $\left(-\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}, -\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\right)=-\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^2}$ is the field of a charged straight wire (the wire is along $z$ axis). Its potential $f$ is $\ln r$ (up to some factor).